# Adding more than 5 tags possibility using [tag:sometag] notation

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

Recently I come across the question from low-rep user:
[Comfortable scroll in web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557136/comfortable-scroll-in-web-page)

He used 10 tags in it by using this notation: `[tag:sometag]`

He just added to the question 10 tags like that:
[sometag1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sometag1) [sometag2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sometag2) [sometag3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sometag3) [sometag4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sometag4) [sometag5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sometag5) [sometag6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sometag6) [sometag7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sometag7) [sometag8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sometag8) [sometag9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sometag9) [sometag10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sometag10)

I edited it and thats all.
But, is it OK that anyone can do it for their questions?

Comment: There are actually just 5 different tags in that question's original revision.

Comment: Is is okay,  No.  What can you do, edit them out.

Comment: Editing it back to just one tag is abusive.

Comment: [Repeated offender](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37437538/1). Perhaps so eone should tell him not to do this. (Also, repeated offender of extremely broad questions.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the body of the question, it won't count as part of the tag indexing or tag search algorithms used on the site, so there's really no *benefit* to using it on a non-Meta post.  Also, it's fairly noisy as a part of the question anyway, so editing it out is the correct response in this case.

It's fine to do it if you need to refer to a specific tag, but again, I see little application of this outside of Meta.